# Passing hidden values to dimple chart

Tags: jquery-mobile, dimple.js

I have a page using jqueryMobile that shows a list of checkboxes. When you select a checkbox it adds a set of numbers to a hidden input. You then click a 'submit' button that goes to the dimple page and it reads the hidden values from the previous page but I want to use those hidden values to filter the dimple chart data.

The problem is that when I submit more than one set of numbers e.g. 001, 002 the dimple chart doesn't show any data.

Do I need to convert the hidden values for dimple to recognise them?

Dimple Code to filter:

data = dimple.filterData(dimple.filterData(data, "ProductCode", passedValues), "OwningDepot", "London");

The values getting passed from a hidden input on the previous page are "001","002","003" so I want to pass those values into the 'passedValues' variable.

Comment: How about showing us the code that generates the chart and explaining what you mean by filter the chart.

Comment: i've added a bit more information to the main question.

Comment: The dimple docs say multiple values should be passed to the filter as an array. Perhaps you can use the javascript split() method to turn your comma delimited list into an array of values: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Using split didn't work. but what i've done is check if the hidden value contains a value e.g. London, Liverpool etc and then create an array with the values 001, 002, 003 and then combine all the separate arrays at the end using concat. its a bit fiddly but it seems to be working. thanks for the help anyway.